# Where is the SKU Number Iphone App

Tags: iphone

Where do I find the SKU number for my iphone app? Is it in xcode somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure. But out of curiosity, what do you need it for? Generally the SKU is just a number you make up to help you keep track of the app on your end, not something you should really need to reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's added when you submit your app to AppStore. Apple uses SKU numbers to distinguish multiple versions of the same app on the iTunes Piano reporting

Answer (score 2):

It is up to you to specify the SKU number. As long as it is unique in your Developer Account, you can name it however you want (alphanumeric).

Answer (score 2):

It's any unique idenfitifer. you may use your App bundle identifier for this because its unique already.